# Merging multiple JSON files with array_merge_recursive

Tags: php, json

I have multiple JSON files (over 120) which I want to merge into one single file using `array_merge_recursive` but I'm getting an `Argument #1 is not an array` error.

Taking two individual files gives me the desired solution, but **trying to loop through all the files** gives me the error.

Any help on this greatly appreciated – I've tried many, many different tweaks on the code below and nothing is giving me any joy.

```
//The folder where the files are kept
$filenames = glob('Week6/*.json');

//Loading one file to start the merge (it has some content),
//convert from JSON format to a usable array
$arrayThree = file_get_contents('newMerge.json');
$arrayThree = json_decode($arrayThree);

//Loop through all of the filenames…
foreach ($filenames as $filename) {

//Get a JSON file from the list
$arrayTwo = file_get_contents($filename);
$arrayTwo = json_decode($arrayTwo);

//Here's where I'm trying to merge the original and the new
//overwriting the initial variable created outside the loop, to be used again
$arrayThree = array_merge_recursive($arrayThree, $arrayTwo);

}

//Encode again as JSON, save out and empty
$arrayThree = json_encode($arrayThree);
file_put_contents("newMerge2.json", $arrayThree);
unset($arrayThree);//release memory
```

Comment: So $arrayThree is not an array. Probably it is null as the json in newMerge.json is malformed.

Comment: You're right @user574632, the original $arrayThree wasn't an array, but even after comparing it to the $arrayTwo in the loop (both now arrays), I'm still getting the same error.